# Visual Studio: design window for ASP.NET web development is greyed out & not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

[Visual Studio design window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGqrf.png)

I tried resetting toolbox, dragging the dotted lines down, but it's not allowing.

The two above lines are only place where I can add anything from toolbox.

The greyed-out box is not allowing to add anything.

Comment: Based on attempts, Albert D. Kallal's solution is correct. If Albert D. Kallal's answer was helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people

Answer (score 0):

There is a new live web preview option in vs2022, and by default it is turned on.

To use the older webforms designer, then

tools->options

Then this:

[image]

I am not sure, but you need to close the existing project for this setting to take effect.

I do VERY much like the new live preview feature in vs2022, and it is somewhat ironic that the best new feature in vs2022 is for webforms!

However, while I do like this new feature, the issue is that it does not support drag + drop from the tool box.

In web form land, we use the designer to help us get a page up and going really fast. And then for fine layout and high-quality previewing, we launch run the application and view in a browser.

While the new live preview is REALLY nice (based on the new chrome rendering engine), and can potentially eliminate the need to run/preview in a browser?

We have to give up the drag + drop design from the toolbox, so like most, I revered back to the legacy web forms designer.

If MS could JUST add the drag and drop back, they would have just made the most killer drag and drop web designer on planet earth.

Anyway, change the above setting and you be able to see/use/enjoy the older webforms designer.